# Momentum Space Representation of the Tight Binding Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, second-quantization, tight-binding, strong-correlated

I am trying to represent the tight-binding Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}_{TB} = \sum_{\sigma} \sum_{\alpha,\beta} \sum_{\mathbf{R}_1,\mathbf{R}_2} 
t^{\alpha,\beta}_{\mathbf{R}_1,\mathbf{R}_2}
\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{\alpha,\mathbf{R}_1,\sigma}
\hat{c}_{\beta,\mathbf{R}_2,\sigma}
\label{eq:Htb}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

in the momentum space, and it is not clear this relation
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\mathbf{R}_1,\mathbf{R}_2} 
e^{-i\mathbf{k}_1 \cdot \mathbf{R}_1}
e^{i\mathbf{k}_2 \cdot \mathbf{R}_2}
t_{\mathbf{R}_1,\mathbf{R}_2}^{\alpha,\beta}
=
\frac{1}{M}
\sum_{\mathbf{R}_0}
\sum_{\mathbf{R}_1,\mathbf{R}_2} 
e^{-i\mathbf{k}_1 \cdot \mathbf{R}_1}
e^{i\mathbf{k}_2 \cdot \mathbf{R}_2}
t_{\mathbf{R}_1 - \mathbf{R}_0,\mathbf{R}_2 - \mathbf{R}_1 - \mathbf{R}_0}^{\alpha,\beta}
\label{eq:pass2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $M$ is the number of lattice sites and the exponentials come out of the Fourier transform of the operators in the real space to those in the momentum space
\begin{equation}
\hat{c}_{n,\mathbf{R},\sigma} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}
\sum_{\mathbf{k}}
e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{R}}
\hat{c}_{n,\mathbf{k},\sigma}
\label{eq:c_R}\tag{3}
\end{equation}
Moreover the translational invariance of the lattice imply 
\begin{equation}
t_{\mathbf{R}_1,\mathbf{R}_2}^{\alpha,\beta} = 
t_{\mathbf{R}_1 - \mathbf{R}_0,\mathbf{R}_2 - \mathbf{R}_0}^{\alpha,\beta} \quad \forall \mathbf{R}_0
\label{eq:hopping_transl} \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

In (2) we can substitute 
$t^{\alpha,\beta}_{\mathbf{R}_{1}-\mathbf{R}_{0},\mathbf{R}_{2}-\mathbf{R}_{0}}$. Then since the left hand side of  (2) does not depend on $\mathbf{R}_{0}$, if we sum on it we have M times the same thing, so if we divide by M, we have a relation equivalent to the previous one